# Scanned bitmap read in sideways, flipped? (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, image, image-processing, bitmap

I have a simple file that reads in a monochrome bitmap (i.e. black and white) and prints out x's to represent the black portion. However, I noticed that for some reason I need to add the code

```
img.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipY);
```

for it to show up "normally." In other words, it seems that something in either my code or the implementation of the built-in functions is rotating and flipping the image as it's read in, acting counter to what I intend.

I'm betting on this is a silly mistake more than "working as intended," so I'm including the relevant code below:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            // Stream objects for capturing image data
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(openFileDialog1.OpenFile());
            MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();

            // Image objects containing image data
            Bitmap img = (Bitmap) Bitmap.FromStream(sr.BaseStream);


            /**** HACK ****/
            //img.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipY);
            /****      ****/


            // Save the image data to our memory stream
            img.Save(memStream, ImageFormat.Gif);

            // Save data to a byte array
            byte[] imgData = memStream.ToArray();

            // Print image data
            for (int x = 0; x < img.Width; ++x)
            {
                Color rgb = new Color();
                for (int y = 0; y < img.Height; ++y)
                {
                    rgb = img.GetPixel(x, y);

                    if (rgb.ToArgb().Equals(Color.White.ToArgb()))
                    {
                       textBox1.AppendText(" ");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        textBox1.AppendText("x");
                    }
                }
                textBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
            }
        }
    }
```

I read in a bitmap of the letter 'B' and it gives me the following.

Without the "hack":

```
     x                         x        
     x                         x        
     x                         x        
     xx                       xx        
     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx        
     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx        
     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx        
     x            x            x        
     x            x            x        
     x            x            x        
     x            x            x        
     x            x            x        
     x            x            x        
     x            x            x        
     x            x            x        
                  x            x        
      x          xx                     
      x         xxxx          x         
      xx       xxx x          x         
       xx     xxxx xx        xx         
       xxxxxxxxxx   xxx    xxx          
         xxxxxxx    xxxxxxxxxx          
           xxx       xxxxxxx            
                       xxx
```

With the "hack":

```
     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx                   
        xxxx         xxx               
         xxx           xxx             
         xxx            xx             
         xxx             xx            
         xxx             xx            
         xxx             xxx           
         xxx             xxx           
         xxx             xxx           
         xxx            xxx            
         xxx           xxxx            
         xxx          xxxx             
         xxx         xxxx              
         xxxxxxxxxxxxxx                
         xxx          xxx              
         xxx            xxx            
         xxx             xxx           
         xxx             xxx           
         xxx              xxx          
         xxx              xxx          
         xxx              xxx          
         xxx              xx           
         xxx             xxx           
         xxx             xx            
         xxx            xxx            
        xxxx          xxx              
     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

I very much look forward to having my mistake pointed out to me. :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Almo: Where do you see that?  OP, you should be `using` those `IDisposable` objects.

Comment: I misread it because I'm so used to the x loop being on the inside. :)

Comment: I'm unsure of whether the .net api's account for this, but bitmaps are stored upside down.  The first byte of the bitmap on disk contains the bottom left pixel of the image.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who answered. I guess this is a classic "my brain is in Friday mode" moment. :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you're building rows with your inner loop to put into the text box, but your inner loop loops over y. Try changing the nesting of those loops, and see what you get. Also, your y loop needs to start at the top, or the image will be upside down.

```
    for (int y = img.Height - 1; y >= 0; --y)
    {
        Color rgb = new Color();
        for (int x = 0; x < img.Width; ++x)
        {
            rgb = img.GetPixel(x, y);

            if (rgb.ToArgb().Equals(Color.White.ToArgb()))
            {
               textBox1.AppendText(" ");
            }
            else
            {
                textBox1.AppendText("x");
            }
        }
        textBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
    }
```

Comment: He also needs to do the height looping backward or the image will be upside-down.

Comment: Thanks for the clear example, particularly on how to reverse the "upside-down-ness" of the image without having to manually flip it.

Answer (score 2):

You're printing it sideways.  Your `y` loop should be the outer loop, so that you write one row at a time.

Answer (score 1):

You have your Width and Height loops backwards.  Your innermost loop is going from the top of the image to the bottom of the image.

Answer (score 1):

It looks as i fyour inner loop is scanning over progressive Y values, with your outer look using different X values.  This is would cause the rotation you are seeing, assuming that the input data was in "normal" scan order.
-- Carl